# React throws "invalid hook error" when initializing Date() in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React throws the error below when trying to initialize the Date object in a functional component made with the "rfc"-snippet. I have no hooks in the component. `let dateObj = new Date()` is the only thing added besides the snippet.

I have checked my React-versions and tried restarting the server. I used create-react-app to create my React project.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

```js
import React from 'react'

function Date() {

  let date = new Date()

  return (
    <div>Date</div>
  )
}

export default Date
```

Comment: change your function name Eg: DateComp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of your function.

```js
import React from 'react'

function CurrentDate() {

  let date = new Date()

  return (
    <div>Date</div>
  )
}

export default CurrentDate
```